# Run multiple shell scripts from one and do something at each finish

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, daemon

I am trying to write a python **daemon**
which will run **multiple shell scripts** at a **same time** on some conditions
and do something on **each task finish**

```
import time
import schedule
import subprocess


def spawn(name, count):
    cmd = 'some long lived shell process'
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdin=DEVNULL, stdout=DEVNULL, stderr=DEVNULL, close_fds=True)
    consumers_dictionary[name] = proc


def thread_task():
    if someconditions
        spawn(name, count)


consumers_dictionary = {}
schedule.every(1).seconds.do(thread_task)
while 1:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

How can I control proc status and do something when process is finished?
Think I need something like promises, or check each my dictionary proc object on status?

P.S. Daemon should be able to work(run and track status) with up to 500 processes

Comment: It is easier to use a `Pool`. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: Thanks, but I have my workers written in another language, looks like I have to run them at least as shell command. Or does Pool provide such option?

Comment: And also I need to change process counts on the fly, up to 100 for one type of worker. Looks like with pool I can't change it's length on the fly

Comment: What do you mean by "control proc status"?  Do you mean "check whether the process is still running"?

Comment: Yes, to check the process is still running or finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check whether a child process has terminated, you can use the `poll()` function of the `Popen` class.  If it returns something other than `None`, the child process has terminated.  In your `while 1` loop with the one-second sleep, you could run through the dictionary of processes and `poll` each one and decide what to do when one has terminated.

From the way you wrote the question, I am guessing that this is what you want.  If you want to get some kind of interrupt when a child process terminates, it looks like that may be possible, but may be platform-dependent.

Answer (score 0):

To wait for a process opened with `popen`, use `wait`. Here's a code sample based on your skeleton:

```
def spawn(name, count):

    processes = [] 
    cmd = 'ls -l ; sleep 2'
    for _ in range(count):
        proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdin=DEVNULL, stdout=DEVNULL, stderr=DEVNULL, close_fds=True)
        processes.append(proc)

    for proc in processes:
        res = proc.wait()
        print(f"process with pid {proc.pid} returned {res}")


def thread_task():
    if True:
        spawn(name = "dummy", count = 5)

schedule.every(1).seconds.do(thread_task)

while 1:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

The result looks like:

```
process with pid 7784 returned 0
process with pid 7801 returned 0
process with pid 7802 returned 0
process with pid 7803 returned 0
process with pid 7805 returned 0
process with pid 7807 returned 0
...
```

Note, that you can also use `poll` to check on the status of a process without waiting for it to complete. ([documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.poll))